# Click event for two dimensional Button array

Tags: c#, windows, events, click

i have a two dimensional button array in c# and i want to create a click event for any button in array.
and when you click on the specific button return the it's place in array.

Generation of buttons:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
   { 
         Num[i, j] = new Button(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: What stops you to do that? How are you creating that button array?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this WPF, Winforms, UWP, or what?

Comment: Care to post your attempt at this? Seems like a pretty simple thing to do.

Comment: i trying to write it in winform

Comment: for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                { 
                    Num[i, j] = new Button();

Comment: If you want to give more information on your question,it's better to edit your question and add there the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give us any code to work with, but I'm giving you a simple solution for your answer.You can add the click event at the same time you are generating the buttons,and use the `Tag` property to store the index. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        Num[i, j] = new Button();
        Num[i, j].Text = "Btn" + i + j;
        Num[i,j].Tag=i+ ","+ j;
        Num[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 80, j * 40);
        Num[i, j].Click += Button1_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(Num[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Then the `Button1_Click` event:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    string[] indexes = btn.Tag.ToString().Split(',');
    //in indexes[0] you've got the i index and in indexes[1] the j index
    Console.WriteLine(indexes[0] + "," + indexes[1]);
}
```

P.S. I don't think you need an array to store the buttons, just add them to the form as shown

Answer (score 0):

Dang. The first answer was posted while I was writing mine! This solution is not much different except:

1. The button text is unique.
2. I avoid splitting the tag just to concatenate it again for the output

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {
           for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
           {
               var button = new Button { Top = 50 * i, Left = 100 * j , Text = $@"Button {i * 4 + j + 1}", Tag = $@"{i},{j}"};
               button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
               Controls.Add(button);
           }
       }
   }

   private static void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   {
       var button = (Button) sender;
       MessageBox.Show(button.Tag.ToString());
   }
   ```